# Selecting strings of repeated digits from an integer

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I need to write a program that, given an integer, finds strings of repeated digits and returns them as an array. For example, given `1234555567899944`, the program needs to return `[5555, 999, 44]`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
a = 1234555567899944
arr = a.to_s.split("")
result = []
arr.each_with_index do |x,y| 
  if arr[y] == arr[y+1] || arr[y] == arr[y-1]
    result << x
  end
end
p result.join().split()
```

Is there a better approach?

How can I get `[5555, 999, 44]` instead of `["555599944"]`?

Answer (score 2):

Input

```
a = 1234555567899944

p a.to_s.gsub(/(.)(?<=)\1+/).map(&:to_i)
```

Output

```
[5555, 999, 44]
```

As Carry suggested,

```
a.to_s.gsub(/(.)\1+/).map(&:to_i)
```

Comment: @spickermann Amazing, thanks. I have included your answer too in the answer.

Comment: You might mention that you are using the form of `gsub` that takes a single argument and no block, and returns an enumerator, and that `scan` can't be used because of the way it treats capture groups.

Comment: @carySwoveland Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 1):

As an exercise I considered how to obtain the desired result without the arguably ugly approach of converting the given integer to a string, manipulating that string to form an array of strings of equal characters and then converting the latter back to integers.

This is one way that could be done.

```
a = 1234555567899944
```

```
buf = nil
arr = []

loop do
  a, digit = a.divmod(10)
  if buf.nil?
    buf = digit
  elsif digit == buf % 10 
    buf = 10*buf + digit
  else
    arr.unshift(buf) if buf > 10
    buf = digit
  end
  break arr if a.zero?
end
  #=> [5555, 999, 44]
```

See [Integer#divmod](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-divmod).

Comment: Despite the ugliness of the approaches I am avoiding, in practice I would hold my nose and go with @Rajagopalan's answer (assuming I coded for a living).

Comment: yes @cary Swoveland you are right we can opt for different approaches to achieve the result but when it comes to the optimal and precise approach we are choosing.

Answer (score 1):

Using Integer#[digits](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits):

```
a = 1234555567899944
p a.digits.chunk(&:itself).filter_map{|_char, chunk| chunk.join.to_i if chunk.size > 1}.reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ruby's [chunk_while](https://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Enumerable:chunk_while) method for this:

```
a = 1234555567899944
a.to_s.split("").chunk_while(&:==).map { |repeated_elems| repeated_elems.join('').to_i if repeated_elems.count > 1 }.compact
```

Comment: You could write `a.to_s.chars.chunk_while(&:==).filter_map { |a| a.join.to_i if a.count > 1 }`. See [Enumerable#filter_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map). Note `slice_when(&:!=)` could be used in place `chunk_while(&:==)`. See [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when).

Answer (score 0):

One could also use `scan` in at least a couple different ways:

```
a = 1234555567899944

a.to_s.scan(/((.)\2+)/).map{|x| x.first.to_i}
#=>  [5555, 999, 44]

a.to_s.scan(/1{2,}|2{2,}|3{2,}|4{2,}|5{2,}|6{2,}|7{2,}|8{2,}|9{2,}|0{2,}/).map(&:to_i)
#=>  [5555, 999, 44]
```

Note that in the first example, the `scan` method captures not only the overall repeating pattern but also the inner `(.)` pattern.  The second approach just explicitly matches specific numbers repeated 2 or more times so there are no extra matches to weed out.